# Is there an effect on root domain email if subdomain CNAME changed?

Tags: cname, 1and1, shopify

I am about to move my website from 1and1 to Shopify, but 1and1 will remain the domain manager.  The website transfer requires me to create a subdomain in 1and1 that is directed to Shopify and also change the `CNAME`.

I did not complete the process because when I changed the `CNAME` as directed by Shopify, a pop up warning from 1and1 stated that after changing `CNAME` all `MX` numbers will be deleted.  I need to maintain the `MX` on the root domain because 1and1 will continue to handle my email.

My question is whether the word "all" in the pop up entails the `MX` numbers on the root domain too or just the `MX` numbers for the subdomain.  I don't want the root domain `MX` numbers changed or I lose email.  I've talked to two 1and1 tech support reps and they cannot seem to give me a straight answer.

Comment: My best advice is for you on this one is to call their tech support and ask for a supervisor if you can. Escalate your issue and do not let the tech support people run you around. See if that gets you anywhere. This is such a specific question regarding your web host, I am not able to help you. Sorry. I wish I could.